# JUnit Test cases for Rest URL

Tags: rest, mockito, resttemplate

I am facing problem to write test cases for a rest url which calls another URL through Rest Template.

Please find my code below:-

```
@RestController
public class ParentController{
@Value("${child.url}")
    private String childUrl;
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplateUtil restTemplateUtil;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/parent",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> callChildController(@RequestBody InputParam inputParam, HttpServletRequest request) {
        return restTemplateUtil.templateService(restTemplateUtil.formURL(request, childUrl), HttpMethod.POST,null,inputParam, Object.class);
    }}
}


@Service
public class RestTemplateUtil {

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    public  ResponseEntity<Object> templateService(String url, HttpMethod method, HttpHeaders headers, ...............){

            logger.info("Rest template service called..");
            response = restTemplate.exchange(url,method,entity,responseType);

        return response;
    }

    public String formURL(HttpServletRequest request, String childUrl){
        return "http://" + request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort() + childUrl;
    }
}
```

JUnit Test case written:-

```
Mockito.when(restTemplateUtil.templateService(Mockito.anyString(),
                Mockito.<HttpMethod> eq(HttpMethod.POST),
                Mockito.<HttpHeaders> any(),
                Mockito.<HttpEntity<?>> any(),
                Mockito.<Class<Object>> any())).thenReturn(mockRespEntity);

                 this.mvc.perform(post("/parent")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(requestObj)))
                .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful());
```

I am a newbie to Mockito, so with my meagre knowledge have build the above test case.
Please advise and correct me if I am wrong.

On executing this, I am getting error:-

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:80/child": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

The portno is wrong here.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: What does your complete test method look like? How is the mocked `restTemplateUtil` injected into your controller?

Comment: I figured out my problem. Have annotated restTemplateUtil wrongly. It should be  @MockBean

Comment: Previously annotated using @Mock. Thanks for ur help Morfic